# SQL Server - Conditional Aggregate - Sum only if ID is not null else dont sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer table below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2jAq.png)

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 30 |
| Null | 5 |
| Null | 10 |

I have column ID and Value in my table and ID can be duplicate.
I would like to sum value column only if ID column is not null. If ID is Null, dont sum and show as it is.

I know I can do Union like below:

```
select ID, sum(Value)
from table where id is not null
group by ID
UNION
select ID, Value
from table where id is null
```

But I would like to achieve the same result using IIF or CASE or any function without UNION
something like:

```
iif(ID is not null,sum([Value]),[Value]) as Value
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Your union approach looks pretty optimal and is how I would probably do it.

Comment: I actually have a large dataset and many columns coming from various joins. Union is taking up alot of time. Im trying to make my query fast so figuring out a way to use some IF else sort of thing to make it fast

Comment: I agree with Tim's comment. Your current query is a clean, well performing from the looks of it, and readable way to do what you're describing. I couldn't find any way to get the behavior you're after without the union.

Comment: Have you profiled the query to know that "union takes a lot of time"? I agree with others that the query you tried is the declarative way to get the data you want. You may need to add some indexes or reorganize the other columns of the query if it is not performant.

Comment: Use UNION ALL rather than UNION, this will be faster. UNION makes sure you will get no duplicates from both queries, but you can't get duplicates here because the result of the first query will never contain rows without id and the result of the second query will never contain rows with an id.

Comment: You could try this alternative: `with data as (select coalesce(id, -row_number() over (order by id)) as id, val from T)
select case when id >= 0 then id end as id, sum(val) from data group by id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try out grouping sets to see if that produces a better plan. This does assume that values (column 2) in the null subset are themselves unique:

```
select id, sum(val) from T
group by grouping sets ((id), (id, val))
having id is null and val is not null or id is not null and val is null;
```

And then there's always an approach that generates a new id for the null id so they can remain distinct during grouping. Here I'm assuming that negative values are open for this purpose but you could probably adjust if necessary:

```
with data as (
    select coalesce(id, -row_number() over (order by id)) as id, val
    from T
)
select case when id >= 0 then id end as id, sum(val)
from data group by id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/fbGbpyEf